# Conditional-marginal KL divergence

Tags: information-theory

I came across the following formula in a research paper and I am having a hard time understanding it.

$KL(q(z|x) || q(z)) = -H(q(z|x)) - \int q(z|x) \log \int q(z|x')p(x')dx'dz$

Could someone explain how this is derived and what is means? I've also attached a screenshot from the paper with the full proof.

[Screenshot from the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdeau.png)

Comment: In general, $$ \mathrm{KL}(P\|Q) = \int p\log(p/q) = \int p \log (p)  - \int p \log(q) = -H(P) - \int p(z) \log(q(z)) \,\mathrm{d}z,$$ where I've dropped the dependence on $z$ in the first two equalities. Now use the law of total probability to find that $$q(z) = \int q(z|x') p(x') \,\mathrm{d}x'.$$ Finally, set $p(z) = q(z|x).$

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for the clear explanation!